# "This will not appear in News Feed." - Relationship

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I try to change my relationship status to single on Facebook and I receive this message in a blue box:

> "This will not appear on the newsfeed."

I would like to know why it won't appear, and why this message is coming up!

Comment: Have you checked your privacy settings? Could you give us a run-down of your preferences there?

Comment: Yeah i checked, everything is public.

Comment: Hmm...it could have to do with the person with whom you were previously in a relationship.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Facebook Community Questions](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200531559024813) thread on this, the only statuses Facebook shows by default in the newsfeed are

> - in a relationship
> - it’s complicated
> - widowed
> - open relationship

However, someone posted a useful workaround wherein you can add the end of your relationship as a "life event" (added emphasis mine).

> Go to your **"About"** section on your timeline and on the right hand side there should be a column that says **"history by year"**. Underneath the events, there will be a little pencil icon thats says **"add a life event"** and from there you can choose the *family and relationships* option and there is something called **end of relationship**. Fill out the details and it will post on people's news feed.